# Kernel of homomorphisms of the Baumslag-Solitar group BS(n,-n)

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I would like to find the kernel of the following homomorphisms and show that those kernels have trivial intersection.

$H:=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\langle p,q| q^n=1\rangle$

$BS(1,-1)=\langle c,d| dcd^{-1}=c^{-1}\rangle$

$G:=BS(n,-n)=\langle a,b| ba^nb^{-1}=a^{-n}\rangle$

$\phi_1' :BS(n,-n)\rightarrow H$ defined by $\phi_1'(a)=q$ and $\phi_1'(b)=p.$

$\phi_2':BS(n,-n)\rightarrow BS(1,-1)=\langle c,d| dcd^{-1}=c^{-1}\rangle$ defined by $\phi_2'(a)=c$ and $\phi_2'(b)=d$

We  have that $N≤\ker(\phi_1')$ where $N$ is  the normal closure of $\langle a^n\rangle$ since $a^n\in\ker(\phi_1')$, but I think $N\neq\langle a^n\rangle$ since $a^n$ and $b$ don't commute. So what is the kernel of $\phi_1'?$

For $\phi_2',$ we have $N′≤ker(\phi_2')$ where $N′$ is the normal closure of $bab^{−1}a$ since $bab^{−1}a\in\ker(\phi_2').$ But is $N′$ equal to $\langle bab^{−1}a\rangle$ and is $N'$ the kernel of $\phi_2'?$

By advance thank you.

Comment: If you add the relation $a^n=1$ to the presentation of $G$ then the resulting presentation simplifies to that of $H$, so the kernel of $\phi_1'$  is  the normal closure of $\langle a^n \rangle$ in $G$, which if equal to $\langle a^n \rangle$ because it's a normal subgroup. And yes, the kernel of $\phi_2'$ is $N'$, but $\langle bab^{-1}a \rangle$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: But I don't see why $\langle a^n \rangle$ is a normal subgroup? I mean why $b^ka^nb^{-k}$ is a power of $a^n?$ We have $ba^nb^{-1}=a^{-n}$ but how can I express $b^2a^nb^{-2}=ba^{-n}b^{-1}$ as a power of $a^n?$ Is there a simple way to express $N'=\langle a^kla^{-k}, b^klb^{-k} | k\in\mathbb{Z}\rangle$ where $l=bab^{-1}a?$

Comment: Yes, $b^2a^nb^{-2}=a^n$.